# Can Gravity Forms be integrated with CiviCRM?

Tags: wordpress, forms, integration

We have a site that has 5 different Gravity Forms currently. They work great and we love them. We're planning on setting up CiviCRM for this organization in WordPress and want to know if its possible to map all the data from our current forms directly into CiviCRM. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

CiviVIP has a paid solution for [Gravity Forms CiviCRM integration.](https://shop.civivip.com/civi-plugins/gravity-forms-integration/) - though depending on what you are doing - it may not integrate with everything you are doing in Civi. (I think it only does activities and contacts)

The CiviCRM WordPress community has galvanized around [Caldera Forms and CiviCRM integration.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf-civicrm/) Which is quite robust.

You may also be able to get away with using [profiles](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/) - depending on what you are doing with your forms.

Comment: I don't know if things have changed - but when I used the Gravity Forms plugin @themak mentions 2 years ago, I thought it was very weak, and Caldera Forms CiviCRM is an improvement in every possible way.

Comment: Caldera Forms is being retired.

Comment: There have been various discussions about whether Ninja Forms will work with CiviCRM in the future - if anyone is interested search https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/ for 'ninja forms'

Comment: Other folk are pinning their hopes on AFFORM and SearchKit in core civicrm providing what might be needed.